# Change latexmkrc by setting file local variable

Tags: latex, auctex, file-local-variables

How can I specify inside a latex file (for example as a local variable) that compiling with `latexmk` should use a `latexmkrc` file with a specific path say `/path/to/latexmkrc` and *not* the default one and *not* that in the current directory.

Here is what I tried:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-r /path/to/latexmkrc"
%%% End:
```

However this doesn't work. If I look at the log window, it starts with

```
Running `Latexmk' on `myfile' with ``latexmk -shell-escape myfile''
Subroutine pythontex redefined at (eval 10) line 6.
Rc files read:
  /home/myuser/.latexmkrc
  .latexmkrc
```

(And `/path/to/latexmkrc` is neither `/home/myuser/.latexmkrc` nor `.latexmkrc`).

**Edit**

The problem seems to be related to `latexmk` if I choose `latex` as compiler, it seems to add the option. Here is how `latexmk` is setup in my `init.el`

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (push '("Latexmk" "latexmk %(-PDF) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
             :help "Run Latexmk on file")
           TeX-command-list)
     ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an `%(extraopts)` to the definition of `Latexmk` in my `init.el` file. This causes emacs to append the `TeX-command-extra-options` to the `Latexmk` command:

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (push '("Latexmk" "latexmk %(-PDF) %(extraopts) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
             :help "Run Latexmk on file")
           TeX-command-list)
     ))
```

Compare `M-x describe-variable RET TeX-expand-list-builtin`:

```
("%(extraopts)"
 (lambda nil TeX-command-extra-options))
```

Nevertheless by looking on the definition of the `LaTeX` command in `TeX-command-list` I noticed that `LaTeX` doesn't include the `%(extraopts)` expand string whereas plain `TeX` does.

```
("TeX" "%(PDF)%(tex) %(file-line-error) %`%(extraopts) %S%(PDFout)%(mode)%' %(output-dir) %t" TeX-run-TeX nil
  (plain-tex-mode ams-tex-mode texinfo-mode)
  :help "Run plain TeX")
 ("LaTeX" "%`%l%(mode)%' %T" TeX-run-TeX nil
  (latex-mode doctex-mode)
  :help "Run LaTeX")
```

Maybe someone could comment, why `LaTeX` parses the `TeX-command-extra-options` variable even without `%(extraopts)` in its definition.